# ReactPHP blocking inside a loop

Tags: php, loops, asynchronous, reactphp

I am trying to achieve a parallel execution of my workers and I'm using `ReactPHP` to help me. https://github.com/reactphp/react

But I'm not getting behaviour that I'm expecting to get.

Scenario:

I have three workers.

`fetch.php`
`parse.php`
`notify.php`

`fetch.php` and `notify.php` don't have prerequired conditions to run, so they can run in parallel and should run first.

`parse.php` needs to wait for `fetch.php` to finish with work and then it should execute.

So i have my parent script `process.php` where all the magic happens.

```
$tasks = ['fetch', 'notify'];

forkProcess($tasks);

function forkProcess($tasks)
{
   if (empty($tasks)) return false;

   $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

   foreach ($tasks as $task) {

       $process = new React\ChildProcess\Process("php $task.php");

       $loop->addTimer(0.001, function($timer) use ($process, $task) {
           $process->start($timer->getLoop());
           $process->stdout->on('data', function($output) use ($task) {
                echo $output;
                $subTasks = getDependentTask($task);
                forkProcess($subTasks);
           });
       });
   }

   $loop->run();

}

function getDependentTask($task)
{
    if ($task != 'fetch') return [];     
    return [
        'parse'      
    ];
}
```

So instead of getting this output:

```
FETCH
NOTIFY
PARSE
```

I am getting

```
FETCH
PARSE
NOTIFY
```

And script waits for parsing to finish and then goes to the next task which is notify.

So I am doing something wrong and since I'm playing around with ReactPHP for the first time its probably some rookie mistake.

Is the problem that I'm using recursion and that is blocking the loop or something else.

Maybe loop was not implemented to solve this kind of problems that I'm trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

Problem is with recursion.

See in my first task fetch i have just a `echo 'FETCH';`

And it's instant so it gets data immediately and it enters .on('data') event and calls function again with new array. So that is a design problem that I'm having.

Figured it out immediately after i posted this question.

If i edit my `fetch.php` worker and set `sleep(1)` before `echo` i get notify worker to output string first.